# SQL select statement fails to retrieve data falling within specified date range

Tags: mysql

I have a query that's meant to return various statistics related to items released within some time period between yesterday and the first of the month last year.  For the most part, the following query works as expected.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.ReleaseDate, '%Y-%m') AS FormattedReleaseDate, COUNT(*) AS ReleaseCount, SUM(A.SalesPrice)/COUNT(*) AS MAPAvg, SUM(B.TotalCost)/COUNT(*) AS COGSAvg
FROM item_info A, status B
WHERE A.ReleaseDate BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2016-02-22'
AND A.ListID = B.ListID
GROUP BY MONTH(A.ReleaseDate)
ORDER BY FormattedReleaseDate DESC
```

This retrieves the specified statistics for every month between 2/1/15 and 2/22/16.  However, it's not returning anything from this month.  Just to check, I ran this exact same query, replacing the start date above with `2016-02-01`, which retrieved the results I expected for just this month.  Out of desperation I tried using a different column from `item_info` that serves the same purpose as `status`' `TotalCost` column, thereby alleviating the need for any sort of table join, but I'm still not getting the results from this month.  I *know* it exists and falls within the date range.  What exactly is wrong with my first query?  I haven't specified a limit to the number of results.

Comment: You should not use ancient style join by comma. Rewrite it to `INNER JOIN`, then test how it works with `LEFT JOIN`. Probably you don't have corresponding row in `status` table or `ListID` at `item_info` is blank.

Comment: I just attempted a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and I'm still getting the same results.  The same is true of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Did you try without joining `status` at all? Post your `left join` version.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should:

```
group by FormattedReleaseDate
```

So if month is repeated in two different years shows as many rows as different pairs month-year are (and not stacking them together in one month, just giving you 12 rows as much).

You should try also:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(A.ReleaseDate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
between STR_TO_DATE('01/02/2015 00:00:00', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
    and STR_TO_DATE('22/02/2016 23:59:59', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

just to ensure your filter is more accurate.

So the entire query would be:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.ReleaseDate, '%Y-%m') AS FormattedReleaseDate, COUNT(*) AS ReleaseCount, SUM(A.SalesPrice)/COUNT(*) AS MAPAvg, SUM(B.TotalCost)/COUNT(*) AS COGSAvg
FROM item_info A, status B
WHERE 
STR_TO_DATE(A.ReleaseDate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
between STR_TO_DATE('01/02/2015 00:00:00', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
    and STR_TO_DATE('22/02/2016 23:59:59', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')
AND A.ListID = B.ListID
GROUP BY FormattedReleaseDate
ORDER BY FormattedReleaseDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't grouping the data properly.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.ReleaseDate, '%Y-%m') AS FormattedReleaseDate, COUNT(*) AS ReleaseCount, SUM(A.SalesPrice)/COUNT(*) AS MAPAvg, SUM(B.TotalCost)/COUNT(*) AS COGSAvg
FROM item_info A, inventory_status B
WHERE A.ListID = B.ListID
AND A.ReleaseDate BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'
AND A.HideInDealerPricelist = 0
GROUP BY YEAR(A.ReleaseDate), MONTH(A.ReleaseDate)
ORDER BY FormattedReleaseDate DESC
```